# Unable to save authorization header in Android using Volley

Tags: android, api, authorization, token

So I am building an **Android** app which talks to an **API**.

Whenever a user logs in, I see the response in the log cat which contains the `user details` including the `authentication` token but the user gets `unauthorized access` although the login is successful.

**My question is**; how do I authorize the user? How do I save the token header in android using `volley`? This concept is new to me. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

After you login, you need to save the session cookie, access token or whatever your api provides. I usually use SharedPreferences.

Later within your next api Request, you need to override the getHeaders();

```
JsonObjectRequest volleyRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(url, null, responseListener, errorListener){
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        // put your accesstoken if available
        params.put("X-CSRF-Token", accessToken);
        // put a session cookie if available
        params.put("cookie", sessionName + "=" + sessionId);
        return params;
    }
};
```

Comment: Still unable to solve my problem because I still get the "unauthorized" error.

Comment: First you need to find out what exactly works with your api, if you don't have a proper API definition, you can test easily with tools like postman https://www.getpostman.com/